# When using @wire I can't get lightning-datatable to show the field value

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, lwc-wire-adapter

I am using `@wire` and `getListUi` to get a list view of accounts. I have a `lightning-datatable` where, for now, I just want to display the name of each account.

Relevant part of the template:

```
<template if:true={listView.data}>
    <lightning-datatable
        key-field="id"
        data={accounts}
        columns={columns}>
    </lightning-datatable>
</template>
```

Here is my JS code with `@wire` and getter for accounts:

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getListUi } from 'lightning/uiListApi';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';

const columns = [
    {
        label: 'Account Name', 
        fieldName: 'Name',
        type: 'text'
    }
];
export default class AccountExample extends LightningElement {
    columns = columns;

    @wire(getListUi, {
        objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT,
        listViewId: '00B5I000001O1O3UAK',
        pageSize: 5
    })
    listView;

    get accounts() {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.listView.data.records.records, null, 4));
        return this.listView.data.records.records;
    }
}
```

In the `console.log()` statement I am seeing all of the values I expect. The `lightning-datatable` does appear to be populated but there is not text showing up. It's as if the text is the same colour as the `datatable` background.

I have seen a few questions on here with a similar problem however they are using `uiRecordApi`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the records data, the name is deep in the records returned by the `wire` method.

```js
[{
    "apiName": "Account",
    "childRelationships": {},
    "id": "0012p00002NlX48AAF",
    "lastModifiedById": "0052p000009CZDSAA4",
    "lastModifiedDate": "2019-06-17T06:57:46.000Z",
    "recordTypeId": "012000000000000AAA",
    "recordTypeInfo": null,
    "systemModstamp": "2019-06-17T06:57:46.000Z",
    "fields": {
        "BillingState": {
            "displayValue": null,
            "value": null
        },
        "Name": {
            "displayValue": null,
            "value": "Burlington Textiles Corp of America"
        },
```

So the data is not directly compatible with the `lightning-datatable`, as the data table expects the name as a first level property.

You can use JavaScript [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to prepare appropriate array, changes to the `accounts` method as bellow gives me account names in the table.

```js
get accounts() {
    console.log('accounts', JSON.stringify(this.listView.data.records.records, null, 4));

    const records = this.listView.data.records.records;

    // use map to prepare a new array of Accounts with Name property
    const accountsJson = records.map(record => {
        let newObject = {}
        newObject["Name"] = record.fields["Name"].value;
        return newObject;
    })
    return accountsJson;
}
```

---

Please note that you may have to do some exception handling while accessing records and the field values - `record.fields["Name"].value`.

Comment: You can use [getFieldValue](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_get_field_value) and [getFieldDisplayValue](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_get_field_display_value) to avoid having to access the record data manually and all the possible errors that could come from that.

Comment: Good point @adraincg, they are part of `uiRecordApi` where as OP is using `uiListApi`

Comment: Thanks! However I am now getting this error intermittently: `Cannot read property 'records' of undefined`. Do I need to make sure that `listView` is assigned before the `get accounts()` function is called from the template?

Comment: Could you verify if the records are available on the list view when you go to the accounts tab?

Comment: They are available. I am using a dev org with just the default set of data and can see all the accounts

Comment: I was using an Id to a custom list view which was just a duplicate of the All Accounts view. I changed to use the default one and it seems to be working now.

Comment: @Raul AFAIK it's all using the [UI api](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_get_started.htm) so those helpers should do just fine, even if the LWC framework expose them from different modules

Comment: @adraincg: the links you posted is for record API which only works with single record but here OP is working with a list of records, so that won't work here. Please let me know if I'm missing anything. :)